# $ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{\sin(x^3)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{\sin(x^3)} =[1]\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x/\cos x-\sin x}{x^3}\\ =[2]\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\\ =\frac{1}{2} $$

My question is how [1]=[2]?

$\tan x-\sin x=\tan x(1-\cos x)=x(1-\cos x)$?

Comment: Is that $sin(x^3)$ or just $x^3$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\sin x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}(1-\cos x)$.
Thus our function is equal to
$$\frac{1}{\cos x}\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}.$$
The limit of $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ is $1$. So is the limit of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

You did not ask about the limit of $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$. That can be obtained by multiplying top and bottom by $1+\cos x$, getting $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{1+\cos x}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2$.

**Remark:** The above answered your specific question. It did not address the question of finding
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x-\sin x}{\sin(x^3)}.\tag{1}$$
For that, we rewrite (1) as
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}\frac{x^3}{\sin(x^3)}.$$
Since $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$, we have $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3}{\sin(x^3)}=1$, and we are at the question you asked.

Comment: thanks, I've checked the steps after [2] by L'Hospital, you give me all details.